# error querying the datatable

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have a datatable that contains only a single field "cl_mt" and another datatable that contains 3 fields "cl_id","cl_description","cl_mt" i'm trying to write the following code:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = serviceTable.Select("cl_id,cl_description where cl_mt='" & CInt(mt_combo.SelectedValue) & "'")(0).Item("cl_cl_id")
```

i need to get all the cl_id and the cl_description from my datatable where the cl_mt is equal to a certain value in the other datatable

the code i'm writing is giving me index error and syntax error

note that both datatables are being filled a comboboxes

any idea how can i improve my query?

Comment: first thing - .Select returns an array of rows, not a datatable

Comment: okey let's say i changed the variable to an array of rows but that did not fix my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Dim dt As String
    dt = serviceTable.Select("cl_mt='" & CInt(mt_combo.SelectedValue) & "'")(0).Item("cl_cl_id")
```

never mind i solved on my own :)